# Why does VS2013 use a non-virtual and a virtual call, respectively, in the first and the second examples below?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, pure-virtual, visual-studio-2013

**First example:** pure virtual function `foo()` is called in the `Base` constructor with a non-virtual call. That explains why the code executes normally, i.e., it doesn't abort like the second example.

```
#include <iostream>
struct Base {
    Base() { foo(); }
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

void Base::foo() { std::cout << "Base::foo()\n"; }

struct Derived : Base { void foo() { std::cout << "Derived::foo()\n"; } };

int main()
{
    Derived d;
}
```

**Second example:** here the pure virtual function `foo()` is also called in the `Base` ctor, but with a virtual call and the code aborts with `R6025 - pure virtual function call`.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    Base() { call_foo(); }
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    void call_foo() { foo(); }
};

void Base::foo() { std::cout << "Base::foo()\n"; }

struct Derived : Base { void foo() { std::cout << "Derived::foo()\n"; } };

int main()
{
    Derived d;
}
```

I know by §10.4/6 that pure virtual functions called from constructors or destructors is considered undefined behavior. But I'm curious to know what could be a reasonable explanation for the different calls to `foo()` in these two snippets?

Comment: So you already knew if was undefined behavious, but asked anyway? There's no reasonable explanation for what you see when you trigger undefined behaviour; just blind luck and the whims of the compiler developers.

Comment: @Rook: Understanding how and why undefined behaviour manifests itself in your particular environment can be very useful when diagnosing it. Dismissing it as ineffable removes a valuable tool from your debugging kit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, it is undefined behavior.  What is 
(probably) happening, however, is that in the first case (the
call in the constructor), the compiler knows the dynamic type of
the object (since it is always the type being constructed), and
so generates the call exactly as it would for calling any
non-virtual function.  (If you had failed to provide
a definition, I imagine that the linker would have complained.)
In the second case, you call the function from within another
function.  At that point, the compiler has no way of knowing the
dynamic type the object will have at runtime; the function could
have been called on a fully constructed object, perhaps of
a derived type not even present in this source file.  Since the
compiler cannot determine statically the dynamic type the object
will have at runtime, it must generate a call through the
virtual function table (or whatever method it uses to resolve
dynamic dispatch, but VS, like everyone else I know, uses
a vptr to a vtable).  Since calling a pure virtual function in
this manner is undefined behavior, the compiler puts a pointer
to an error handling routine in the vtable.

Note that in this case, the compiler *could* have seen that the
call in the constructor of `Base` would resolve in a manner
which causes undefined behavior, and generated code which would
have triggered the error.  Or... since all of the virtual
functions of `Base` are pure virtual, the compiler could have
known that the cannot be called during construction, and not
even bothered to create a separate vtable for `Base`, perhaps
initializing the vptr to point to the vtable of `Derived` before
calling the constructor of `Base`.  You can't count on anything
such cases.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, calling the function directly from the constructor, the dynamic type is known at compile time, so there's no need for virtual dispatch. The compiler can generate a direct call to `Base::foo`.

In the second case, calling it from another function which could be called at any time on any type derived from `Base`, the dynamic type is not known at compile time and so virtual dispatch is necessary.

As you say, this is undefined behaviour; in principle, anything could happen in either case. I would hope for a compiler warning in the first case (GCC gives one); but in the second case, the error is only detectable at runtime (if at all).

Comment: From your answer and looking at other examples I conclude that MS compilers make virtual calls only when necessary. Strange that they do this even in a debug build, when optimizations are normally absent. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Well, *undefined behavior* means that anything may happen; including potentially surprising events like appearing to work or throwing an exception.

Now, given that VS chose to abort when a call to a pure-virtual is emitted during construction or destruction; I suspect that the first behavior (calling `Base::foo`) is actually a bug (according to *their* specifications). It would be so trivial for the code that devirtualize a function call to miss the special case of failing to compile if the called method is *pure*.

Comment: VS doesn't throw an exception. It aborts.

Comment: @MSalters: thanks, I compared it to gcc's behavior when I read it and somehow managed to exchange the two.

Comment: @MatthieuM. g++ aborts in this case, or at least it used to.  (Go back far enough, and it aborted without an error message.)